# Logging in to the correct Azure instence

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, azure

I have access to 2 Azure Subscriptions.
One is the Developer one I get from having MSDN (Developer Program Benefit).
The other is the company subscription (Currently an Enterprise Agreement but was converted from PayAsYouGo).

I am a Global Administrator in both.
For both subscriptions I use my Microsoft Account. (Because MS is having some problem with company logins and AzureADs).

When in the Azure portal (portal.azure.com) I can switch subscriptions using the drop down in the top right.

When I use Visual Studio (Professional 2015 and Ultimate 2013) I can not use the Company Subscription.
In Visual Studio (either) when I select:

Server Explorer | Azure | Manage and Filter Subscriptions

I get a dialog **Manage Microsoft Azure Subscriptions**.  In the Subscription tab I can see both my Subscriptions.  However the company subscription is marked with a warning and the message.

"This subscription is not supported by Server Explorer"

I get a similar problem when using Powershell.  When I set my credentials using  Add-AzureAccount and then use Get_AzureSubscription I can only see my MSDN subscription.

I want to be able to use Powershell and Visual Studio with the company Azure subscription.  What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior could be due to either of your subscriptions don't support classic deployment model (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-deployment-model) for more information). For example Azure CSP subscription doesn't support classic resources.

Don't use Server Explorer for Azure subscriptions in Visual Studio, use Cloud Explorer instead (in VS 2015 from top menu choose View - Cloud Explorer). Cloud Explorer supports all types of Azure subscriptions.
For Powershell try below:

```
Login-AzureRMAccount
```

or

```
Add-AzureRMAccount
```

then

```
Get-AzureRMSubscription
```

Comment: The Add... and the Get... worked but then I get a problem that I suspect is the underlying problem.  I've edited my question.

Comment: I don't see significant changes in your question. Note that I am using Resource Manager commands: Login-Azure**RM**Account,  Get-Azure**RM**Subscription

Comment: You've likely been given "Owner" access to your company's sub via RBAC.  When you have access to a sub via RBAC you can only access it through AzureRM apis - so it's not really about the type of subscription but how you've been given access to it.  Tomasz is correct, you need to access this subscription via Cloud Explorer (in VS) and via AzureRM cmdlets in PowerShell (and Azure Resource Manager mode in CLI).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't edit my question as I got distracted :-).
My non working subscription had brackets in its name.  Once I renamed the subscription without brackets it started working in both Powershell.